# Laravel Auth::check() fails when I move to another site and come back

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to connect to a eBay store from my Laravel application. When I login to  my system and create a store I am redirected to the eBay.com site where I approve the token generation.

Then eBay generates the token and redirects to the callback URL on my site. By that time my site gets me logged out and redirect to the login page.

The Laravel version I am using is 5.3 and following is the piece of code which checks for authentication. Also, I am using the default id column as primary key.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $loginUser = Auth::user();
    $ebay_sessionId = $loginUser->ebay_session_id;
} else {
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the login process code? With the routes and the controller that it's handling it?

Comment: Could you share some code to explain what you mean?

Comment: You have to share your code! Anyway I explain myself a little better... I think the application problem is the `Auth::check()` that is called before the user session is started... That's why I was asking you to post the code pre redirect to ebay and after the redirect

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using Laravel's built in authentication?

Comment: It is the built-in authentication. Here I am getting the user and the value associated with the user

Comment: We'll need to see more code. The point where you are redirecting to eBay and the point where eBay are coming  back into your application. Show use the controller(s) that handle that as well as the route.

Comment: Share your code that is pushing user to ebay and the callback function that handle your ebay redirection. Seems like your session getting flashed when you are redirected from ebay, since you using laravel default auth system

Comment: Can you share middleware codes?

Comment: If you are specifying routes in api.php, you will need to use the auth:api middleware.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/53-api-routes-auth-middleware-confusion

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, where sometimes my app was connected to the default database *"forge"* specified at *database.php* in the configuration as follows

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
```

Here I removed `env()` and replaced it with my database name directly as string, and it worked.

```
'database' => 'my_db_name'
```

Since you have an issue with the session, give it a try by removing `env()` in *session.php* in the config folder.

Comment: That made the trick. Do you have any idea why it fails with env file? When I hard coded the session driver to 'file' it works but when I read from the env file it sometimes works but not otherwise. Have an idea?